# How to Interface for a module in javascript

Tags: javascript, indexing, module, interface, weekday

I am just beginner to javascript. I ought to replace **blablabla** with a code which output the following

There are 7 days in a week.

In programming, the index of Sunday tends to be 0.

Here is the code

```
const weekday = (function() {
   const names = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];


**blablabla**



})();

var num = 0;

console.log("There are " + weekday.count() + " days in a week.");
console.log("In programming, the index of " + weekday.name(num) + " tends to be " + weekday.number(weekday.name(num)) + ".");
```

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Which is fine but [be aware of the guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). I suppose the first question is: do you understand the code that you've posted in your question?

Comment: Hi Andy, somehow yes! But when I am applying the interface, an error message is poping up saying that I should initialize it first. So, I would like to get your support in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to understanding this is realising that the immediately-invoked function (IIF) needs to return an object and assign it to `weekday`, and that object needs to contain functions (or references to functions) that you can call.

For example: `weekday.count()` - `weekday` is an object that has a function assigned as a value to its `count` key. That object is what is returned from the IIF and assigned to `weekday`. `weekday.count()` calls that function.

So the IFF should contain the following functions:

1. `count` - returns the length of the `names` array.
2. `name` - returns the element in the `names` array at the index you supply as an argument.
3. `number` - returns [the index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) of the "weekday" string you pass in as an argument.

Then add references to those functions to an object which is returned from the function and assigned to `weekday`.

```js
const weekday = (function() {
  
  const names = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

  function count() {
    return names.length;
  }
  
  function name(n) {
    return names[n];
  }

  function number(str) {
    return names.findIndex(el => el === str);
  }

  return { count, name, number };

})();

const num = 0;

console.log(`There are ${weekday.count()} days in a week.`);

console.log(`In programming the index of ${weekday.name(num)} tends to be ${weekday.number(weekday.name(num))}.`);
```

Additional documentation

- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Now I have got the key point of the solution. Frankely, I did not expect this. I was focusing on the return interface. However, the key point of the solution was how to link the 2 functions (number and name) to the declared variable in the beginning. I was busy in the return interface code.